# Awk function, syntax error near unexpected 'myArr,'

Tags: bash, function, awk, syntax, arguments

I am not sure why my simple function causes "Syntax error near unexpected 'myArr,'. I taking an array, lookup key value and a line item section name as arguments. Each row in the array is "," delimited string. I am checking if the first string equals the look key value. If it does I will print out the row to my output file. I am using awk. I have the function outside of the awk being script.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

Authorization="Authorization.csv";
LineItem="LineItem.csv";
ModifierCode="ModifierCode.csv";
Decision="Decision.csv";
LineItemReview_CRLI="LineItemReview.csv";
LineItemReview_ARLI="LineItemReview.csv";
#AuthorizationNotification
#InformationSource
#LineItemNotification
#LineItemReview
#Note & NoteComment

OUTFILE="output.csv"
function LineItems(myArr, AuthKey, LIsection){
        for (LI in myArr)
        {
            split(myArr[LI], a, ",")
            if (a[1] == AuthKey) 
            {
            print LIsection"," myArr[LI] > "output.csv"
            }
        }
}



awk 'BEGIN  { NR>1

     while (getline < "'"$Authorization"'" )
    {
            split($0,ft,",");

            Auth_num=ft[4];
            request_date=ft[5];
            status=ft[8];
            state=ft[9];
            state_date=ft[10];
            request_source=ft[12];
            method=ft[13];
            level_of_urgency=ft[17];
            urgency_requested_by=ft[18];
            primary_diagnosis=ft[19];
            primary_code=ft[20];
            continuity_of_care=ft[21];
            court_ordered=ft[22];
            member_eligibility_and_benifits_verified=ft[23];
            single_case_agreement=ft[24];
            case_name=ft[25];
            requesting_provider=ft[28];
            requesting_provider_id=ft[29];
            requesting_provider_npi=ft[30];
            requesting_provider_phone=ft[32];
            requesting_provider_phone_ext=ft[34];
            requesting_provider_fax_number=ft[36];

            Authorization_Arr[Auth_num]=Auth_num","request_date","status","state","state_date","request_source","method","level_of_urgency","urgency_requested_by","primary_diagnosis","primary_code","continuity_of_care","court_ordered","member_eligibility_and_benifits_verified","single_case_agreement","case_name","requesting_provider","requesting_provider_id","requesting_provider_npi","requesting_provider_phone","requesting_provider_phone_ext","requesting_provider_fax_number;

    }
        close("'"$Authorization"'");

        LineItCounter=0;
        while (getline < "'"$LineItem"'")
        {

            split($0,li,",");
            LineItCounter=LineItCounter+1
            LI_Auth_num=li[4];
            LI_ID=li[5];            
            line_item_number=li[6];
            requested_from_date=li[7];
            requested_to_date=li[8];
            type=li[9];
            requested_date=li[10];
            determination_due_date=li[12];
            service_type=li[13];
            status=li[14];
            level_of_urgency=li[15];
            urgency_requested_by=li[16];
            primary_procedure=li[18];
            code=li[19];
            applied_eligibility=li[20];
            servicing_provider=li[21];
            provider_id=li[22];
            npi=li[23];
            in_network=li[24];
            servicing_provider_phone=li[26];
            place_of_service=li[28];
            comments=li[29];
            method=li[30];
            out_of_network_reason=li[31];
            preliminary_requested_units=li[33];
            request_source=li[34];
            determined_from_date=li[35];
            determined_to_date=li[36];
            determination=li[37];
            requested_units=li[39];
            recommended_units=li[40];
            determined_units=li[41];
            type_of_decision=li[42];

            LineItem_Arr[LI_ID]=LI_Auth_num","LI_ID","line_item_number","requested_from_date","type","requested_date","determination_due_date","service_type","status","level_of_urgency","urgency_requested_by","primary_procedure","code","applied_eligibility","servicing_provider","provider_id","npi","in_network","servicing_provider_phone","place_of_service","comments","method","out_of_network_reason","preliminary_requested_units","request_source","determined_from_date","determined_to_date","determination","requested_units","recommended_units","determined_units","type_of_decision;    

        }
            close("'"$LineItem"'");

        Modcounter=0;
        while (getline < "'"$ModifierCode"'")
        {

            split($0,mi,",");
            Modcounter=Modcounter+1
            Mod_Auth_num=mi[4];
            Modifier_ID=mi[5];
            modifier_code=mi[7];

            ModifierCode_Arr[Modcounter]=Mod_Auth_num","Modifier_ID","modifier_code;

        }
            close("'"$ModifierCode"'");

        Deccounter=0;
        while (getline < "'"$Decision"'")
        {
            split($0,di,",");
            Deccounter=Deccounter+1;
            Dec_Auth_num=di[4];
            Dec_LineItemID=di[5];
            Decision_ID=di[7];
            decision2=di[8];
            units=di[9];
            decision_date=di[10];
            claim_information=di[11];
            explanation=di[12];

            Decision_Arr[Deccounter]=Dec_Auth_num","Dec_LineItemID","determined_units","decision2","units","decision_date","claim_information","explanation;

        }
            close("'"$Decision"'");

        LIR_counter=0;
        while (getline < "'"$LineItemReview_CRLI"'")
        {
            split($0,ri,",");

                LIR_counter=LIR_counter+1;
                LIR_Auth_num=ri[4];
                date_of_review_CRLI=ri[7];
                reviewed_by_lastname_CRLI=ri[8];
                reviewed_by_firstname_CRLI=ri[9];
                external_reviewer_CRLI=ri[10];
                criteria_met_CRLI=ri[12];
                method_CRLI=ri[14];
                administrative_denial_CRLI=ri[15];
                criteria_source_CRLI=ri[16];
                review_summary_CRLI=ri[17];
                review_notes_CRLI=ri[18];
                rationale_CRLI=ri[19];

            LineItemReview_CRLI_Arr[LIR_counter]=LIR_Auth_num","date_of_review_CRLI","reviewed_by_lastname_CRLI","reviewed_by_firstname_CRLI","external_reviewer_CRLI","criteria_met_CRLI","method_CRLI","administrative_denial_CRLI","criteria_source_CRLI","review_summary_CRLI","review_notes_CRLI","rationale_CRLI;

        }
            close("'"$LineItemReview_CRLI"'");

        ARLI_counter=0;
        while (getline < "'"$LineItemReview_ARLI"'")
        {
            split($0,ai,",");

                ARLI_counter=ARLI_counter+1;
                ARLI_Auth_num=ai[4];
                date_of_review_ARLI=ai[7];
                reviewed_by_lastname_ARLI=ai[8];
                reviewed_by_firstname_ARLI=ai[9];
                external_reviewer_ARLI=ai[10];
                reviewer_specialty_ARLI=ai[11];
                criteria_met_ARLI=ai[12];
                review_reason_ARLI=ai[13];
                criteria_source_ARL=ai[16];
                review_summary_ARLI=ai[17];
                review_notes_ARLI=ai[18];
                rationale_ARLI=ai[19];


            LineItemReview_ARLI_Arr[ARLI_counter]=ARLI_Auth_num","date_of_review_ARLI","reviewed_by_lastname_ARLI","reviewed_by_firstname_ARLI","external_reviewer_ARLI","criteria_met_ARLI","reviewer_specialty_ARLI","review_reason_ARLI","criteria_source_ARL","review_summary_ARLI","review_notes_ARLI","rationale_ARLI;

        }


            close("'"$LineItemReview_ARLI"'");



             for (key in Authorization_Arr)
             {   
                if (key != "authorization_num") 
                { 
                    print "SASH," Authorization_Arr[key] > "output.csv" 

                    for (LI in LineItem_Arr)
                    {
                        split(LineItem_Arr[LI], a, ",")
                        if (a[1] == key) 
                        {
                            print "SPLI," LineItem_Arr[LI] > "output.csv"
                        }
                    }

                    for (Mod in ModifierCode_Arr)
                    {
                        split(ModifierCode_Arr[Mod], p, ",")
                        if (p[1]== key) 
                        {
                            print "SPLI_Mod," ModifierCode_Arr[Mod] > "output.csv"
                        }

                    }

                    for (Dec in Decision_Arr)
                    {
                        split(Decision_Arr[Dec], d, ",")
                        if (d[1]== key) 
                        {
                            print "SPLI_Dec," Decision_Arr[Dec] > "output.csv"

                        }

                    }

                    for (CRLI in LineItemReview_CRLI_Arr)
                    {
                        split(LineItemReview_CRLI_Arr[CRLI], u, ",")
                        if (u[1]== key) 
                        {
                            print "CRLI," LineItemReview_CRLI_Arr[CRLI] > "output.csv"

                        }

                    }

                    for (ARLI in LineItemReview_ARLI_Arr)
                    {

                        split(LineItemReview_ARLI_Arr[ARLI], c, ",")

                        if (c[1]== key) 
                        {
                            print "ARLI," LineItemReview_ARLI_Arr[ARLI] > "output.csv"

                        }

                    }

                }
            }       








    }'
```

Comment: You are probably trying to execute awk program with 'bash'. If you code is in cmd-file, you should execute it like 'awk -f cmd-file'. Alternatively, you can embed the awk script into a shell function.

Comment: I am trying to call the function in the awk script. I declare the function outside of the awk begin script

Comment: I am call the script from the command line bash merge.sh

Comment: You are only showing an isolated `awk` function definition. Please show how you are actually *using* it.

Comment: Also `awk` version.  Earlier versions did not fully support array parameters to functions fully.

Comment: The code you posted is fine. The most likely thing is you have a problem in some other part of your script that you haven't shown us. Come up with a minimal complete script that demonstrates the problem and post that (but you'll almost certainly solve the problem yourself by trying to do that).

Comment: I added my full script. You can see why I created the function. I wanted to call the function to replace the nested for loops.

Comment: I still can not figure out what awk version I am running. How would I find out which awk verison I am running.

Comment: I didn't ask for you to just throw up whatever script you had lying around, I asked for you to create and post a **minimal script** that demonstrates your problem. See [ask] if that's not clear. Having said that, you see to have an awk function lying around in the middle of a shell script. That'd certaily cause your shell interpreter to recognize it as a syntax error!

Comment: How will LineItems be used ? There is no reference to it.

Comment: Knowing what OS you are running on will help us know if you can "safely" use `awk`, so please post output of `uname -srv`. You might get a version number from awk by `awk --version` or `awk -V`. Add that if you get a result. Good luck.

Comment: Hang on - is that `!/usr/bin/gawk -f` before your script actually part of your script? You seem to be mixing shell and awk syntax. Shell is not awk. They're 2 complete separate tools with their own languages. You can call an awk script from a shell script just like you can call a C program from a shell script, that's all.

Comment: I am running AIX 1 7 that is the return value when I typed uname -srv. I am using LineItem as such; LineItem (LineItem_Arr, Key, "SPLI")

Comment: Your `awk` function is not inside the `awk` script!

Comment: When I put the function into the awk script is still produce the same error. This is my first time using awk and shell script. I am learning on the go.

Comment: It seems too much time spent (wasted?) on this script before getting familiar with the programming language.  Start small and grow your program incrementally.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a project to complete, so I do not have time to master shell and awk. I understand what my script is doing but just do not understand why the function wouldn't work.